# Simple @font-face from MDN guide not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-size

I'm trying to replicate a simple example [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) and it's not working.

**html file**

```
<body>
  Hello world!
</body>
```

**css file**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold";
  src: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/2468/VeraSeBd.ttf");
}

body { font-family: "Bitstream Vera Serif Bold", Arial;
font-size: 10rem}
```

[Live codepen example](https://codepen.io/mcancode/pen/LYZXPbz).

Comment: Instead of using live path use local path will help.

Comment: @SumitPatel I've tried local paths as well with webpack 5, still doesn't work. I just don't understand what's causing it. And are there any alternatives?